# java array rotating by n element gives wrong output in test

Tags: java, arrays, rotation

I have a problem with an exercise trying to solve it. Here is the task:

Write a program that moves that rotates a list several times (the first element becomes last).

```
list = 1,2,3,4,5 and N = 2 -> result = 3,4,5,1,2
```

Note that N could be larger than the length of the list, in which case you will rotate the list several times.

```
list = 1,2,3,4,5 and N = 6 -> result = 2,3,4,5,1
```

Input
On the first line you will receive the list of numbers.
On the second line you will receive N

Output
On the only line of output, print the numbers separated by a space.

Here are the TEST:

> TEST 1:
>
> Input 5,3,2,1 2
>
> Output 2,1,5,3
>
> TEST 2:
>
> Input 2,1,3,4 5
>
> Output 1,3,4,2

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine();

        String[] elements = input.split(",");
        int[] array = new int[elements.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            array[i] = Integer.parseInt(elements[i]);
        }

        int a = scanner.nextInt();


        int[] rotated = new int[elements.length];


        for (int x = 0; x <= array.length - 1; x++) {
            rotated[(x + a) % array.length] = array[x];
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < rotated.length; i++) {

            if (i > 0) {
                System.out.print(",");
            }
            System.out.print(rotated[i]);


        }
    }
}
```

The first TEST is passed. But the second test is not passed and my program gives me wrong output:  4,2,1,3 instead of the right one: 1,3,4,2.

I cant figure it out where is the problem.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Clearly your problem is the direction of rotation. Test 1 rotates twice on 4 elements so the direction doesn’t matter and I recommend using meaningful variable names, as I’m not sure a is easy to make sense of.

Comment: Thank you guys for your suggestions! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic can be simplified to :

```
public static void shiftLeft(int shiftBy, int arr[]) {
    for (int j = 0; j < shiftBy; j++) {
        int a = arr[0];                         // storing the first index
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {  // shifting the array left
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        }
        arr[i] = a;                             // placing first index at the end
    }
}
```

Now call it :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //  Fetch all data from user as you have done

    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    shiftLeft(n % arr.length, arr);

    // print out the array
}
```

Notice that if the number `n` is greater than the *length* of the array, you don't have to actually shift it that many times. Instead you just need to shift it `n % arr.length` times.

Comment: Thank You very much Nicholas K ! Your solution works for me and passed all tests.